# Make the tour page a bit more specific

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Right now if a user visits the tour page (https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/tour) a question about `How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies?` is highlighted.

Can the question on the page be one that is a good question so brand new users can see a good example of one? Moderators should be able to edit that particular aspect of the tour page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample Q&A on the Tour has to meet some specific criteria. From [What determines the questions available for selection in the tour page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947)

> Apparently the posts have to be short, with at least two short answers (<=400 chars). They also shouldn't have any crazy formatting.

with [a link to find suitable Q&A on the site](https://data.stackexchange.com/freelancing/query/92078/possible-about-questions).

Unfortunately, as of current writing, it seems there's no Q&A pair on this site that meets the criteria...